# Change nickname upon sending a message

Tags: discord

This might seem like a rather odd question, but is it possible to automatically change your own nickname within a certain server upon sending any message? My experience with js or py is almost zero, so I don't even know where to start. I'd really appreciate a detailed explanation if this can be done.

Comment: Using [tag:discord.py] you can call the [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) coroutine to change a nickname.  If you want to change the nicknames of other users, you need the Manage Nicknames permission.

Comment: Alright, how do I do that if I only want my own nickname to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) to change the nickname of your bot.  Here is a bot that increments it's name whenever it responds to the message `Hello`

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

counter = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global counter
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if "hello" in message.content.lower():
        if message.guild is None:
            return
        counter += 1
        await message.guild.me.edit(nick=f"Responses: {counter}")
        await message.channel.send("Nickname changed")

client.run("your token")
```

Comment: Let's assume I'd like to run a self-bot, that would react whenever I send a message from the same account. Essentially it would change its own name upon detecting a message sent "by itself". Is it possible?

EDIT: And by message, I mean any message at all

Comment: Yes, you would just change the `hello` check to check that `message.author.id` equals your id.